# Terminal not printing certain characters

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-14.10

Edit: This problem suddenly fixed itself after an hour or two. I'm still curious to know the cause if someone knows, however.

My terminal is not showing certain characters. So far it seems to be limited to capital letters - I've discovered it is not printing E, T, or W. For example, submitting the command "echo ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" results in a terminal log:

```
ajr@lenovo:~$ echo ABCD FGHIJKLMNOPQRS UV XYZ
ABCD FGHIJKLMNOPQRS UV XYZ
```

Note the characters disappear in BOTH lines, but only after the command is submitted. Highlighting this output and copy/pasting it to another medium (such as the text editor in Google Chrome) actually reveals the "hidden" characters properly in the new medium, but pasting the output back into terminal does not show the character until I highlight the offending character with the terminal's text cursor.

This is happening on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.10 on a Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro. What could be causing this?

Comment: This could have been cosmic radiation hitting your computer and flipping a bit in its memory. Or a temporary fluctuation in power supply leading to a similar result. This could break your font or some drawing routine temporarily. Things happen, computers are just machines.

Comment: What happens if you change the terminal's font size?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are able to select/paste the text, it sounds like a problem with the font, or with the X display driver (some accelerated drivers in every release seem to produce lots of bug reports).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try flushing the write buffer? I faced this problem in ubuntu as well, but while i was working with ssh, that is because of the speed and the process interrupts when the write buffer is full waiting to lock the kernel space